# How to add and use non native cordova plugin in ionic 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-plugins

I am trying to use this plugin in my Ionic 5 app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-k-nfc-acr122u

I installed plugin using cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-k-nfc-acr122u and i i dont now like use it. Plugin declares :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkRSs.png)

and i try use connect function but it don't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxsFE.png)

package.json
[image]

Please help, thx.

Comment: check this plugin "https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc"

Comment: thx for your suggestion. I need only k-nfc-acr122u plugin becouse i have usb nfc adapter and i try connect to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, maybe it will be useful to someone,
Import

```
 import { KNfcAcr122U } from 'plugins/cordova-plugin-k-nfc-acr122u/types';
```

I declare:

```
 const kNfcAcr122U: KNfcAcr122U = window['KNfcAcr122U'];
```

and I use the connect function:

```
kNfcAcr122U.connect(this.callbackSuccess, this.callbackError);

callbackSuccess(event): void {
  console.log(event,'success');  
}

callbackError(): void {
  console.log('error');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the plugin `KNfcAcr122U` from `cordova-plugin-k-nfc-acr122u` in your component after importing in app.module.ts.

Then in constructor you can declare a private variable
`private kNfcAcr122U : KNfcAcr122U`

and in you function:

`this.kNfcAcr122U.connect()`

and

`this.kNfcAcr122U.disconnect()`

Comment: Thx, but i dont importing in app.module.ts. I have such a mistake : 'KNfcAcr122U' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts